# html_data to show prechecked jstree

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jstree

I am trying to show the menu using jstree checkbox. I've followed this link http://www.mattfrear.com/2011/12/17/jstree-revisited/ but i've tweaked it to fetch data from the database to show menu dynamically.

When using json_data as described i've been able to precheck the particular nodes at the startup. But when i pass model from controller and use html_data for the same, i can see the tree with checkbox but it is not prechecked. Can't I use html_data to precheck the nodes??

Comment: did you find this, if yes, then post your answer as I want also bind data via model as a html format.

Answer (score 0):

BJ,

You can try making your html format as below

> ```
> <div id="tree">
>     <ul>
>         <li >
>             <a href="#">Node 1</a>
>             <ul>
>                 <li>
>                     <a href="#">Node 1.1</a>
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <a href="#">Node 1.2</a>
>                     <ul>
>                         <li class="jstree-checked">
>                             <a href="#">Node 1.2.1</a>
>                         </li>
>                     </ul>
>                 </li>
>             </ul>
>         </li>
>         <li class="jstree-checked">
>             <a href="#">Node 2</a>
>         </li>
>     </ul>
> </div>
> ```

The catch here is that you need to add

> `<li class="jstree-checked">`

to the node that needs to be selected onload. Since you are dispatching the markup from server, you can check the same and add the class where applicable.

-- Arvind.